# what if a coin is spendable by multiple keys?

Tags: script

it seems like the scripting language could allow multiple private keys to spend a coin?

what if i send a coin to someone, but also allow it to be spendable by me. would their wallet still show they received the $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the wallet. To recognise the transaction at all, their wallet would have to have the script / multisig address in it too. They'd have to have done that themselves, you can't generally trick someone because their wallet simply wouldn't see the transaction at all.

Comment: right, obviously depends on the wallet. i was asking about the current popular ones. you're saying they wouldn't recognize it, because it's a weird format? that's good!

Comment: Yep! A multisig address starts with a 3 and is indistinguishable from any other address starting with a 3 unless you have the corresponding script

Comment: do you need a multisig address to do something like this? you can't lock a coin for 1 of 2 normal bitcoin addresses?

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar That's essentially what a multisig does. You supply m public keys, and say an output can be spent by n of those keys signing the tx (an n of m multisig).